# Изменение стиля для n-количества ячеек в столбце OPENPYXL

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

Необходимо изменить стиль текста в ячейках, условно, с D19 до D21, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реальзовать в openpyxl? 
 
У меня только получилось для всего столбца:

```py
for cell in ws['D']:
    cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center',
                               vertical='center')

    cell.font = Font(name='Times New Roman',
                     size=14,
                     color='FF0000')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку cell это tuple, соответственно можно вытянуть из него значение, т.е cell[0], вот решение:

```py
for cell in ws['D19:D21']:
    cell[0].font = Font(name='Times New Roman',
                     size=14,
                     color='FF0000')
    cell[0].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center',
                                  vertical='center')
```